# How do I msgpack the below parameters to send in a CURL?

Tags: python, curl, msgpack

device_id={UNIQUE_ID}&key={CUSTOMER_KEY}

I have tried following as many examples as I could find online, but there really wasn't a lot that was helpful for me.  I'm using Python and have imported the msgpack and did this:

```
msgpack.packb([device_id:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000,customer_key:0123456789abcdef])
```

But I get an error it's invalid syntax, with the colon indicated as the offending character.  I wanted to out the msgpack code into a CURL and send it.  But so far, I'm doing something wrong in how I define my key/values here.

Comment: You should probably use a dict and not a list. `msgpack.packb({"device_id":"00....", "customer_key":"..." })`

Comment: No that doesn't work either....  I also tried it with the use_list flag set to false...still no joy:

msgpack.packb(["customer_key":"0123456789abcdef","device_id":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"], use_list=False)

Comment: Well, I may have figured it out.  I put the entire thing into single quotes...but it seems that most of it emerged only semi-msgpacked?  Odd.

Here were the results:

'\x91\xda\x00Ldevice_id=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&customer_key=0123456789abcdef'

Does that look proper?